# Не работает css с htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^rooms/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/? table.php?table=$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/? index.php?chairs=$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Нужно получить `domain.com/tables/wood` вместо `domain.com/?table=lux`
И `domain.com/wood` вместо `domain.com/?chairs=wood`

Но с приведенным кодом работает только второе правило, и то пропадают css и изображения, хотя путь к ним начинается с `/`.

Comment: а причем здесь css?

Comment: @makcim512 ваще хз, при данных правилах не работает контент

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как это делается

> В другом примере преобразуем www.site.ru/script.php?product=123 в www.site.ru/cat/product/123/:
>   RewriteRule cat/(.*)/(.*)/$ /script.php?$1=$2